# How to avoid encoding of special characters in xmlroot

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I trying to serialize a class JTDChanges with different xmlrootname "ns1:BatchChanges" but after serializing when I write it into a file, "ns1:BatchChanges" is encoded to "ns1_x003A_BatchChanges".

This is my class

```
[ Serializable, XmlRoot("ns1:BatchChanges") ]
    public class JTDChanges
    {
        [XmlElement("OrgUnitChanges")]
        public List<OrgUnitStage> CustomerChanges = new List<OrgUnitStage>();
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I avoid the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Xml Namespace functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("BatchChanges, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/2008/xsdl-exx/ns1") ]
public class JTDChanges
{
    [XmlElement("OrgUnitChanges")]
    public List<OrgUnitStage> CustomerChanges = new List<OrgUnitStage>();
}
```

Now before this really has a effect, you also need to tell your serializer to use this namespace

```
// Create a name space prefix
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("ns1", "ttp://www.w3.org/XML/2008/xsdl-exx/ns1");

// Create a serializer
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

// And pass the namespace along as param
ser.Serialize(writer, this, ns)
```

As for a test you could declare the following

```
 [XmlElement(ElementName = "point", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/2008/xsdl-exx/ns1")]
```

which would result in 
`<ns1:point>(whatever the values were you declared it upon)</ns1:point>`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But it also cahgnes all my xml nodes from OrgUnitChanges to ns1:OrgUnitChanges. I want ns1 to be appended only to root node.

Comment: @SriHarsha There are plenty of posts here on SO [which explain you how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571394/serialize-part-of-xml-file-want-namespace-on-root-not-on-serialized-subelement). If this answer helped you don't forget to accept it as a answer/up vote it for other people to see