# Avoid encoding of special characters in xmlroot in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, xml-serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently if i serialize the below model to xml in asp.net core . we are getting *x003A* in place of colon (:) . As we dont explictly serialize the xml in webapi ,
Is there any attribute through which we could avoid the encoding .

```
    [XmlRoot("ns1:Customer") ]
    public class Customer
    {      
    }
```

EDIT : we can avoid the encoding by using XmlSerializerNamespaces . But In ASP.netcore , an inbuilt xml serializer is present . Can we add the Namepsaceprefix in asp.net core

Comment: Did you see this sir? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237316/how-to-avoid-encoding-of-special-characters-in-xmlroot

Comment: Yes . This scenario is in case where we implement the serializer . But an inbuilt xml serializer comes in case of asp.net core